# Best way to have a table with editable cells in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have a rails backend, with multiple automobiles each with their own attributes. So the data arriving at the erb form looks like this:

```
automobile[]['color']
automobile[]['type']
.
.
.
times 20 car attributes, times 100 automobiles
```

I need to be able to display and edit this massive amount of information in the browser and then return it to server for processing. 
Simple forms with input boxes are unweildy and take up a lot of screen space.

I was wondering what alternatives/best practice is for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, one alternative is to implement some kind of in-table editing (preferably using a library of some kind), and **asynchronously** update the entire row "on blur". That way you don't have to worry about transmitting the entire contents of the table, and you can keep your routes RESTful.

By "on blur", I mean an event that is fired whenever the user has finished editing a particular field, which you would use to fire off your asynchronous update (aka ajax).

A great example of this can be found on the [DataTables - Editor](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple.html) page. While that is a paid product, in my opinion it is well worth it. There is also an open source [Bootstrap-enabled in-table editor](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/); while I have not used it myself, it looks like it would get the job done nicely.

The advantage of using either of these libraries is that they will handle the event delegation and ajax requests for you, all you need to do is configure the URL.

Comment: I looked at those, the problem is all this data isn't stored in models or anything due to a sort of poorly built code base,  so I'm passing it to the front end with a Hash!  So dynamic single unit transactions aren't really possible.  I was hoping to have basically just a form that looks like a table or something.

Comment: @Nickthemagicman To be specific, what do you mean by *the data isn't stored in models*; are you manually loading the data from the database, thus producing a hash?